# Extending interface signature without editing code in multiple places

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface

I have an interface and existing code which implements this interface:

```
public interface IBusinessService<T> where T : class
{
    Task Add(T category);

    Task Delete(T category);

    Task Update(T category);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();

    Task<T> GetById(int id);     
}
```

Now some `id` has type of `Guid`. So I cannot use this method to send `Guid` id:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid()
var result = GetById(id);
```

So we need that `id` parameter can be type of `Guid`. It would be ideal if it is possible:

```
public interface IBusinessService<T> where T : class
{
    /* ... the other code is omitted for the brevity */
    Task<T> GetById(Guid or int id );     
}
```

What I thought to implement is to create a new method with parameter type of `Guid`:

```
public interface IBusinessService<T> where T : class
{
    Task Add(T category);

    Task Delete(T category);

    Task Update(T category);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();

    Task<T> GetById(int id);     

    Task<T> GetById(Guid id);     
}
```

But if I will do this, then I need to edit so many code. So it looks like it is  not a good solution.

Is there a way to add another type of `id` to the interface method `GetById` without breaking changes?

Comment: You can use default interface implementation, if working with the latest C# 8. You also try to do it using a base abstract class, if it's valid option for your

Comment: If it doesnt matter if id is `int` or `guid`, why is there even both? If it does matter you will need both overloads obviously. Also there exists no conversion between `int` and `guid`. Only way around it is to use `object`. Thats the problem with generaliztaion of things that are specialized.

Comment: @CSharpie no, I need just one method but type of `id` can be sometimes either `Guid` or `int`

Comment: @Learner why do you think you need one method?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for the response. However, we are using C# 6.0. And base abstract class allows to change type of parameter in derived classes?

Comment: @CSharpie because front end sends `id` with type of `int` or `Guid`.

Comment: @Learner and frontend doesnt have a clue what it is doing?

Comment: @CSharpie sorry, what do you mean? I cannot understand what you mean

Comment: @Learner changing type isn't allowed, but you can have default implementation and override it only where needed

Comment: @Learner the frontend will probably know it wants a CarPart with the Id 4711 or a Customer with the guid xyz. It will probably not try to get a CarPart with guid xyz.

Comment: Actually, the question looks like a violation of [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). It's better to split one complex interface into multiple ones and implement them where it's really needed

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski do you mean to create two interfaces `public interface IFooInt<T>  { Task<T> GetById(int id); }` and `public interface IFooGuid<T>  {  Task<T> GetById(Guid id);  }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a design problem (interface/API design) in the first place. It should be clear from the beginning whether IDs are represented by a `Guid` or a raw `int` value. But not both. Usually you try to use a protocol to control the client-server communication or at least by defining a server API. This protocol would define what values the API expects and the client must take care to input them in the correct format.

Consider to stay with the `int` ID an use a custom conversion from `Guid` to `int` where required. Alternatively introduce a table (`Dictionary`) where you store pairs of `Guid` and `int` values. So for each `Guid` that enters your application you internally generate a integer which will replace the `Guid`. But there must be some constraints or algorithm to guarantee the uniqueness of the IDs especially when using `int` values. But I assume when you are using `int` for unique IDs you already have an algorithm to generate those IDs.

Adding members to an interface is always a breaking change.

Since you are not using C# 8 you can't make use of the new Default Interface Method feature.

So, if you can accept breaking changes then you could refactor the interface to take one more generic parameter for the `id` parameter.
You could also change the type of the `id` parameter from `int` to `object`. But this would also introduce the costs of boxing/unboxing (in order to convert value types like `int` to `object`). I personally think using either `object` or `string` would be the best. I don't know your web interface but `string` could be the preferred ID type.

So the best solution, in case you can't accept those breaking changes, would be to implement a new interface e.g., `IGuidIdBusinessService<T>`:

```
public interface IGuidIdBusinessService<T> : IBusinessService<T> where T : class
{
  Task<T> GetByGuid(Guid id);
}
```

Implementing the interfaces:

```
public class MyClass : IGuidIdBusinessService<object>
{
  #region Implementation of IBusinessService<object>

  ...

  // Either throw NotSupportedException or implement conversion
  public async Task<object> GetById(int id)
  {
    Guid guid = ConvertIntToGuid(id);
    return GetByGuid(guid);
  }

  #endregion

  #region Implementation of IGuidIdBusinessService<object>

  public async Task<object> GetByGuid(Guid id) => throw new NotImplementedException();

  #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the problem as big as you describe -- *"But if I will do this, then I need to edit so many code"*

How many implementations do you have. 20? Key here, implementation vs usages. Usages can be many or very many.

Looks like your goal is to keep usage intact as

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var result = someInst.GetById(id);
// or
var id = 5;
var result = someInst.GetById(id);
```

No problem, you need minimal changes. This happens all the time

```
public interface IBusinessService<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> GetById(object id);    // NOTE - change to 'object' 
}
```

Now, you just need to change only few of your implementations that you have to distinct `Guid` from `int`

```
public Task<T> GetById(object id)
{
    if (id is int i)
        return ProcessIdAsInt<T>(i);
    else if (id is Guid g)
        return ProcessIdAsGuid<T>(g);
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Supplied data type not supported");
}
```

So, the changes are minimal. Usages will remain intact. Nothing unusual.